# Importing very large dumps into a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, import

I've asked this in the official MySQL Forum but had no luck, so I'll try it here.

Original thread:
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?28,498593,498593#msg-498593

I'm trying to create a Wikipedia copy and I'm almost done, but have problems with the largest file.

Wikipedia offers database dumps for download, so everybody can create a copy of Wikipedia.

You can find example files here: 
http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20091103/

I've imported almost all of them but am stuck with the biggest one (pagelinks). I imported it for nearly five days, then I had to stop the import. I think the import is slow because of the settings for my MySQL Server, but I don't know what I should change. I'm using the standard Ubuntu MySQL config on a machine with a decent prozessor and 4 gig RAM. Could someone help me out with a suitable configuration for my system? I tried same configs for large servers from the net but the result was that my server didn't start because of an socket error and I had to start over from scratch...

If you can, please have a look into some of the dumps because I think the problem is related to how they are build as some of the smaller files took very long ti import while some of the larger files were imported in a few minutes.

Comment: If you want some help you must post your mysql config and a 4GB ram seems not very much for a database that is 10GB.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a project to target very fast import of very large mysql databases: https://github.com/homer6/import-geoip-data. O.K. 300 MB isn't so large but it is still interesting. Usually to import a .sql file I write thks:

```
mysql -p -h DBSERVER dbname [tablename] < dbfile.sql
```

Maybe you can split the big file into smaller tables?